# Cannot create table in myslq 8.0

Tags: sql, mysql

I am getting an error when i am trying to create a table in mysql command line as shown in the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twmMJ.png)

I was trying to create a table and got a syntax error 1064 stating I have an error in the syntax.

Comment: I was seeing a comma "," after "favourite_food" which might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your SQL syntax. The CREATE statement does not contain a comma after the table name.

```
  CREATE TABLE favorite_food (
  person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
  food varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (person_id,food),
  FOREIGN KEY(person_id)  REFERENCES person (person_id)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE favorite_food(
person_id SMALLIT UNSIGNED,
food VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (person_id,food),
FOREIGN KEY(person_id)  REFERENCES person (person_id));

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain how your statement is different fro the original and how that solves the problem. And you should format code with the `{}` button.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).